# Prevent mousedown event on input range html element and still let user drag slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So is there a way to disable mousedown and / or click event on input range element but at the same time let user drag slider around and still fire on change event?

Disable clicking on line but still enable slider to be dragged around.
I would like to prevent users to jump (with mousedown / click) in the middle of slider but I wanna let them drag it so value changes.

```
<input id="slider" name="slider" type="range" value="-1" min="-1" max="30" step="1" />
```

This does not help as on change for range gets called and messes up numbers.

```
$slider.on('mousedown', function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    this.value = -1;
    /* Act on the event */
    console.log("mousedown");
});
 $slider.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.value = -1;
    /* Act on the event */
    console.log("click");
});
```

If I call `event.preventDefault();` on mousedown slider does not work and can not be dragged around. Is there a way around that.

I am trying to recreate this effect in html is there any jQuery effect for this kind a zoom?

Comment: The example doesn't work buddy.

Comment: @belthazorNv Yeah, the links are broken. But just imagine an `<input type=range>` where the knob is movable, but you can't move it by clicking on the slider outside of the knob. I'm really trying to just figure out how to differentiate between the knob and the slider on the `mousedown` event, to make dragging the knob work correctly with this other method (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988195/can-i-make-a-range-inputs-value-step-up-and-down-on-click).

Comment: Ah ok, I understand what you want.

Comment: I'm not too sure if its possible, why not just opt for a slider such as jQuery UI?

Comment: click and change are working - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oPjRwG , disable mousedown? you mean not to trigger mouse event on click and change

Answer (score 22):

You can use CSS [pseudos-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) to give the `thumb` of the `input` `pointer-events:auto` (allow mouse events) and give the rest of the range input `pointer-events: none` (do not allow mouse events).

See: [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```css
input[type=range]{
  pointer-events: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb{/*Webkit Browsers like Chrome and Safari*/
  pointer-events: auto;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb{/*Firefox*/
  pointer-events: auto;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb{/*Internet Explorer*/
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

## Here's a pure CSS solution

You can control parts of the range with CSS and in that way disable the pointer events for all of those parts them except the `thumb` of the slider. In this way, click events are only registered when the button of the slider is clicked.

```
pointer-events: none;          // disable all event on the range
```

Use the pseudo-class selectors to target the thumb and cover all major browsers like this.

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {   // support webkit (e.g. Chrome/Safari)
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {       // support for Firefox
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb                // support for IE
```

Here's how that would look in action.

```js
$("#slider").on('mousedown', function(event) {
  console.log('Mouse-down: only fired when thumb of the range is clicked');
});
$("#slider").on('mouseup', function(event) {
  console.log('Mouse-up: only fired when thumb of the range is clicked');
});
```

```css
input[type=range] {
  pointer-events: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="slider" name="slider" type="range" value="-1" min="-1" max="30" step="1" />
```

More information on pointer-events can be found in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try:

```
//First block control click + move event
var current_value = $("#slider").val();
$("#slider").on('mousedown', function(event) {
    $("#slider").on("mousemove", function (e) {
    if ($("#slider").val() == parseInt(current_value)+1
    || $("#slider").val() == parseInt(current_value)-1) {
      current_value = $(this).val();
    } else {
      $("#slider").val(current_value);
    }
    })
});

//Second block control click on line
$("#slider").on("mouseup", function() {
      if ($("#slider").val() == parseInt(current_value)+1
    || $("#slider").val() == parseInt(current_value)-1) {
      current_value = $(this).val();
    } else {
      $("#slider").val(current_value);
    }
})
```

NB : if you move to fast the slider, it will jump step, and then back to initial position.

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/674502/

Answer (score 0):

You could use pure CSS

```
#slider {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use "**mouseup**" instead of "**click**"?

```
$("#slider").on('mousedown', function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    console.log("mousedown", this.value);
});
 $("#slider").on('mouseup', function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    console.log("mouseup", this.value);
});
```

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?  [Experiment with the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5st7/) if you'd like. :-)

Comment: I am trying to achieve this effect. Notice how slider isn't clickable. Can not be set to number but can be dragged around.

http://learn.genetics.utah.edu/content/begin/cells/scale/

On the side note is there any jquery effect for this kind a zoom?