# Can I make a range input's value step up and down on click?

Tags: html, user-interface, input

Say I have an `<input type=range min=0 max=100 step=1 />`. If I focus the input, then move up and down with the keyboard, the value changes accordingly. When I click an arbitrary point along the range, the value jumps to where I clicked my mouse. That makes sense for many applications, but can I alter this behavior to make the value step up and down instead, as if I had moved the arrow keys up or down? This makes sense for many scientific applications.

I couldn't find info specifically on mouse behavior in the range input's spec here:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#range-state-(type=range)

Maybe someone here has an answer?

Comment: Don’t think that is available as a default functionality. You could perhaps implement it yourself, if you lay another element on top of the input, so that you can “catch” the clicks there; and then you would have to figure out if that click happened to the left or right of the current position/value, to know whether you have to increase or decrease the value. But than dragging the “knob” to set a value would not work any more. Might perhaps make more sense (and would be a lot easier to implement) if you just offered additional [+]/[-] buttons next to it, so that the user can click those.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: @MarcoSalerno, if you have Flash installed, you can see the behavior I'm trying to get in this flash program. Experiment with the sliders on the bottom - see how clicking to the right and left of the knob behaves. https://cse.unl.edu/~astrodev/flashdev2/transitSimulator/transitSimulator017.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script> var oldValue = 50; </script>
<input type=range max=100 step=1 oninput=" if (oldValue) { this.value = this.value > oldValue ? oldValue + 1 : oldValue - 1; } oldValue = parseInt(this.value, 10);">
```

Comment: Nice solution but it still blocks the handler

Comment: Thanks! The dragging behavior is slightly off, but it basically works, and maybe can be improved. The click behavior is perfect. I'll post my final version here once it's done - I'm doing some adjustments to make the step size dynamic, and making this work in my React application.

Comment: Here's a React component based on zcorpan's method: https://github.com/ccnmtl/astro-interactives/blob/master/small-angle-demo/src/RangeStepInput.jsx

Comment: For anyone interested, here's a version that doesn't constrain the knob dragging behavior: https://pastebin.com/XRFjmbR8, and in React: https://pastebin.com/HZE7419W

Answer (score 0):

I just made it for you:

```js
$("#rangecontainer").mousedown(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var rangeInput = $(this).children();
  var actualValue = parseInt(rangeInput.val());
  if(event.pageX > (rangeInput.position().left + 15 + actualValue)){
    rangeInput.val(actualValue+1);
  }
  else{
    rangeInput.val(actualValue-1);  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rangecontainer"><input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" /></div>
```

Edit:
By adding 15px to the left you avoid the position balancer bug

Comment: Thanks!! Amazing. It's almost perfect. I can probably take it from here though. Two things: 1. the up/down difference should be defined at the point that the knob is at, not the center of the slider. 2. dragging the knob should still be possible.    I can probably implement this in JavaScript, but I was really hoping for some configuration in the HTML standard that just does this automatically.

Comment: Not only does this prevent dragging the handle (if this function is needed), but in my case the point where the direction switches is not aligned with the handle.

Comment: I'm sure that it must be handmade, anyway I gave you a starting point, hope it helps! ^^